# How in MATLAB to set all but every 3rd element to 0?

Tags: matlab

My vector is `[a(1) a(2) a(3) a(4) a(5) a(6) ... a(3k)]`.

I want to get a vector `[0 0 a(3) 0 0 a(6) ... a(3k)]`.

What's a **short** way to do that in MATLAB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this, one is to use the modulo property - since you are after every third element:

```
a = rand(1,3000); %Generate a random vector named a
inda = 1:size(a,2); %Generate the Index Vector of a

third = mod(inda,3) ==0; %Set every third element to 1 and everything else to 0
result = a.*third  %Vector element by element product
```

One line would be:

```
result = a.*(mod(1:size(a,2),3) ==0); %change 3 to any Nth element you want.
```

Another practical approach is to reshape - however this requires your vector to have 3*N in length, otherwise it becomes messy

Comment: Doesn't there exist one line solution? Otherwise writing a for loop in Java would require less code than this...

Comment: @mercury0114 This is actually a 1 line solution, I suppose there are other 1 liners.

Comment: @mercury0114 you don't need it, check the updated answer, sorry, I was writing another answer for another question

Answer (score 4):

An option is to use [indexing](https://nl.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) (slicing in many other languages). Here is a solution with a new variable:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
a =

   1   2   3   4   5   6

>>> r = zeros(size(a))
r =

   0   0   0   0   0   0

>>> r(3:3:end) = a(3:3:end)
r =

   0   0   3   0   0   6
```

And here is a solution 'in place'

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
a =

   1   2   3   4   5   6

>>> a([1:3:end 2:3:end]) = 0
a =

   0   0   3   0   0   6
```